# HTML5 Youtube wrapper works in jsfiddle but not in WP?

Tags: jquery

I've included few file src's and html into my webpage just as shown in jsfiddle.
I put the stuff into php file, since wordpress texteditor tends to ruin code.

The video doesn't work even in separate page template.
Help? :/

[Code on my website](http://trenni.ee/Treening/fittest-spordiklubi/)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAD5q/1/)

Comment: you have the order of the scripts reversed compared to the jsfiddle version. look at your browser's error console to see the errors it's producing.

Comment: This was the correct answer. I just reversed order of 2 lines of script code. Thank you so much ! How can I accept this as 'the answer' (it's a comment and doesn't have such option)?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/00225hizc8), I can see it's working.

However, taking a look at the source code, I found you have two instances of jQuery. You might want to remove the first one found just below the opening `<html>` tag. It's not only the improper way to enqueue jQuery, but may also conflict with the other one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. It's been over 15 hours straight, struggling this this one thing hah.
Did you mean this jquery from header.php?
 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js

Also, how do you mean you "can see it's working"? I tried 3 different browsers and the video won't start. Also mediaelementjs doesn't work, same thing :S